# BlackMagic hyperdeck Connection failed

Tags: blackmagic

I've got a Blackmagic hyperdeck and a computer. Their are both connected on the same network.
The network settings of the hyperck are :

```
Remote : ON
DHCP:OFF
IP address:192.168.1.100
```

I can ping the ip address provided by the hyperdeck.

```
$ ping 192.168.1.100
>>11 packets transmitted, 11 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
```

But when I try to connect myself with telnet for a TCP connection it failed :

```
$ telnet 192.168.1.100 9993
>>Trying 192.168.1.100...
>>telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.100: Connection refused
```

Do I have to configure something else on the hyperdeck or the computer ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was just a simple mistake in the IP address - not anything to do with Video Production.

Answer (score 0):

We made a new set up but my computer had a new IP which was the old hyperdeck IP. And the switch of the hyperdeck was off.
So if was pinging my own computer.

I switch on the switch, change the ip adress, it work back again.